# Что значит запись вида " int (*xNext)(sqlite3_vtab_cursor*); " в языке си?

Tags: c

Что значит запись в языке си вида:

```
int (*xNext)(sqlite3_vtab_cursor*);
```

это поле структуры, но что она значит?
Я такое не нашел в учебниках. Не являюсь программистом си,
но пытаюсь написать обертку к библиотеке.

Comment: вот эти скобочки, это что?

Comment: [Близкий пример](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*xNext%29%28long*%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xNext` — имя поля структуры (идентификатор).

`int (*)(sqlite3_vtab_cursor*)` — тип этого поля: указатель на функцию, принимающую на вход указатель на объект-курсор и возвращающую `int`.

Указатели на функции – по сути, единственные возможные в С функциональные объекты, то есть такие, которые можно исполнять, приписав справа скобки: `int next = obj.xNext(cursor);`

Comment: а вот например вида int (*xUpdate)(sqlite3_vtab *, int, sqlite3_value **, sqlite3_int64 *);  функция принимает указатель. указатель на указатель и третий указатель?

Comment: @yuriy: исходя из вашего комментария становится понятно что, 1й и 2й параметры являются входными, а 3й и 4й выходными. Т.е. если фукнция будет выполнена успешно, она заполнит структуру `sqlite3_value` данными (выделение памяти может лежать на вас/или нет) а так же в `sqlite3_int64` запишет некоторое значение.

Comment: @yuriy Между двумя первыми указателями еще `int` затесался.

Comment: @bipll да, пропустил, пересидел за монитором уже)

Answer (score 2):

`int (*xNext)(sqlite3_vtab_cursor);` - это переменная типа указателя на функцию.
 `int (xNext)(sqlite3_vtab_cursor);` - предварительное объявление функции.